# Find configured domains accepted by a reverse proxy

Tags: brute-force, dns, fuzzing

## Context

I am playing around with a machine from [hack the box](https://www.hackthebox.eu). I found what appears to be a squid v. 4.6 listening on port 3128. None of my requests works

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: squid/4.6
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2020 23:27:28 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 3505
< X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0
< Vary: Accept-Language
< Content-Language: en
< X-Cache: MISS from unbalanced
< X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from unbalanced:3128
< Via: 1.1 unbalanced (squid/4.6)
< Connection: close
```

Among the possible reasons, the displayed error page mentions that **Missing hostname** is the most probable one. I am looking for a way to find this (these) domain name(s)

## Find domain without the help of any DNS server

Since this machine is meant to be accessed with a VPN only, there is no point in using **DNS crawlers** such as `dnsmap` or `dnsenum`. There is no DNS server on this machine nor in this lab environment (that I know of).

There is no `fail2ban` nor any brute-force preventing mechanism so I thought about **brute forcing the domain name**. All the http fuzzers I know allow to fuzz nearly anything except domains. Do you know such a tool of do I need to script it myself?

Do you think of a more straightforward approach?

Comment: Oftentimes, there may be a domain convention e.g. <boxname>.htb. IIRc, wfuzz could be used to fuzz subdomains in this case. Also, just a guess, but have you tried a host header of "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: I just tried <boxname>.htb and localhost. Did not make the trick. Either I am supposed to find it an other way or **missing domain** is not the reason for this 400. I tried to curl it in https and got `error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`. Looks like this server communicates with old fashioned SSLV3 (which is not supported anymore by curl nor my browser)

Comment: that error may just be since the service actually isn't using SSL. Curl should be able to speak SSLv3 if you tell it to, though, iirc.

Comment: The `-3` option does not work with my `curl`, for my local instance of **openssl** has been built without. But you are probably right since this somewhat misleading error message occurs every time I try *curling* an Http enpoint using https